# Set mouse cursor position in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-desktop

Is it possible to set the position of the mouse cursor using Flutter for desktop?

I'm sure this is possible using custom plugins, but I'm hoping for a cross-platform Dart solution or an existing plugin.

Comment: have you found any way to set the pointer position on the Windows desktop in Flutter?

Comment: @KaranSingla It looks like there's a package that provides direct access to some win32 APIs, including the one for setting the mouse cursor: https://pub.dev/documentation/dart_winapi/latest/user32/SetCursorPos.html - I haven't tested this, but it's something to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionality built into Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

Make a method channel between and call SetCursorPos function on cpp file.

```
SetCursorPos(int x, int y)
```